# How to send kafka matching data to other topic

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

How to push matching data  between topic 1 and topic 2 in another topic 3 ?
when sending messages from producer to consumer?

Comment: Kafka does not provide such functionality. You have to implement your own consumer\producer that will read both topics, match messages and transfer to 3rd topic.

Comment: Thanku for the reply.one more question  only thru Consumer and Producer API's in Kafka? We cannot use any storm/spark/flink

Comment: can we use Spark/Flink/Storm to do that matching and pushing message to Topic3?

Comment: Sure. There is some observations: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34448362/1437693

Comment: How to transfer matched messages from 2 different topics to topic3

Comment: Can we that using SPARK? If yes how? Can we use events for sending one topic messages to other topic.    .....Using spark streaming we can send messages only to consumer right but not to topic???? Can you clarify

Comment: I do not have a lot experience with Spark, but I believe it is possible. You can ask in spark thread.

Comment: did the answer help you @Siva Sai If yes can you please accept it ?

Answer (score 1):

I have not worked with **Spark** but I can give you some direction form **Apache Storm** perspective [Apache Storm](http://storm.apache.org/)

1. Build a topology with 2 *kafka spouts* each consuming from *topic1* and *topic2*
2. Consume this data in a bolt and compare the data. You may use single bolt or series of successive bolts. You may need to use some persistence viz. `mongodb` or something such as `redis` or `memcache` , depending on you comparison logic
3. Push the common data to new *kafka topic* [Send data to kafka from Storm using kafka bolt](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.3.4/bk_storm-user-guide/content/ref-0bb85307-f39e-49e4-99a4-2cc741441dc9.html)

This is very `Apache Storm` specific solution, may not be the most *ideal* or *suitable* or *efficient* one, but aimed to give general idea

Here is a link to basic concepts in storm [Storm Concepts](http://storm.apache.org/releases/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/Concepts.html)

Answer (score 0):

I've been working with Spark for over six months now, and yes it is absolutely possible. To be honest, fairly simple. But putting spark on is a bit exaggerated for this problem. What about Kafka Streams? I have never worked with them, but should this not solve exactly this problem?

If u want to use spark:
Use the Spark Kafka integration (I used spark-streaming-kafka-0-10)  to consume and to produce the Data, shoud be very simply. Than look for the Spark streaming Api in the documentation.

A simple join about the 2 DStreams should solve the problem. If u want to store Data who doesn`t match u can window it or use the UpdateStateByKey function. I hope it helps someone. Good Luck :)