# Spark Streaming Design for 1000+ topics

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql

I have to design a spark streaming application with below use case. I am looking for best possible approach for this.

I have application which pushing data into 1000+ different topics each has different purpose . Spark streaming will receive data from each topic and after processing it will write back to corresponding another topic.

```
Ex. 

Input Type 1 Topic  --> Spark Streaming --> Output Type 1 Topic 
Input Type 2 Topic  --> Spark Streaming --> Output Type 2 Topic 
Input Type 3 Topic  --> Spark Streaming --> Output Type 3 Topic 
.
.
.
Input Type N Topic  --> Spark Streaming --> Output Type N Topic  and so on.
```

I need to answer following questions.

1. Is it a good idea to launch 1000+ spark streaming application per topic basis ? Or I should have one streaming application for all topics as processing logic going to be same ?
2. If one streaming context , then how will I determine which RDD belongs to which Kafka topic , so that after processing I can write it back to its corresponding OUTPUT Topic?
3. Client may add/delete topic from Kafka , how do dynamically handle in Spark streaming ?
4. How do I restart job automatically on failure ?

Any other issue you guys see here ?

Highly appreicate your response.

Comment: I think you should look at Kafka Streams for such usecase. https://www.confluent.io/blog/introducing-kafka-streams-stream-processing-made-simple/

Answer (score 5):

1. 1000 different Spark applications will not be maintainable, imagine deploying, or upgrading each application.

You will have to use the [recommended "Direct approach"](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-0-8-integration.html#approach-2-direct-approach-no-receivers) instead of the Receiver approach, otherwise your application is going to use more than 1000 cores, if you don't have more, it will be able to receive data from your Kafka's topic but not to process them. From [Spark Streaming Doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#input-dstreams-and-receivers) :

> Note that, if you want to receive multiple streams of data in parallel in your streaming application, you can create multiple input DStreams (discussed further in the Performance Tuning section). This will create multiple receivers which will simultaneously receive multiple data streams. But note that a Spark worker/executor is a long-running task, hence it occupies one of the cores allocated to the Spark Streaming application.

2. You can see [in the Kafka Integration](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html#obtaining-offsets) (there is one for Kafka *0.8* and one for *0.10*) doc how to see in which topic belongs a message
3. If a client **add new topics** or partitions, you will need to update your Spark Streaming's topics conf, and redeploy it. If you use Kafka 0.10 you can also use RegEx for topics' name, see [Consumer Strategies](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html#consumerstrategies). I've experienced reading from a **deleted topic** in Kafka 0.8, and there was no problems, still verify ("Trust, but verify")
4. See [Spark Streaming's doc about Fault Tolerance](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#fault-tolerance-semantics), also use the mode `--supervise` when submiting your application to your cluster, see [the Deploying documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#launching-applications-with-spark-submit) for more information

To achieve exactly-once semantic, I suggest this Github from Spark Streaming's main commiter : https://github.com/koeninger/kafka-exactly-once

**Bonus**, good similar StackOverFlow post : [Spark: processing multiple kafka topic in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34430636/spark-processing-multiple-kafka-topic-in-parallel)

**Bonus2**: Watch out for the soon-to-be-released Spark 2.2 and the **Structured** Streaming component

Comment: Thanks. Regarding reading parallel topic using spark, do you suggest any optimum that can be configured ? and Ideally in production cluster how many spark streaming application we should launch ?

Comment: About Kafka's consumers,I would suggest these slides, and be sure to print the last slide in your office :) https://fr.slideshare.net/ConfluentInc/when-it-absolutely-positively-has-to-be-there-reliability-guarantees-in-kafka-gwen-shapira-jeff-holoman 

I can't tell you a number for the number of spark application for a cluster, it depends on your cluster's capacity