# How to get data from multiple topics in one place for processing?

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I have a requirement where I have to get messages from 3 kafka topics as stream data and then to generate result based on Joins between these 3 topics data. Please suggest me a good approach using Direct Stream for Scala.
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34430636/spark-processing-multiple-kafka-topic-in-parallel

Comment: @ChaitanyaWaikar Please suggest as which is the better approach, one Direct Stream for multiple topics by providing sparkConf.set("spark.streaming.concurrentJobs", "4") or to have one Direct Stream per topic. Say I have 3 topics so to have 3 Direct Streams in one app. Thanks

Comment: It depends. There has been some talk that using spark.streaming.concurrentJobs leads to unexpected behavior. Creating separate streams for each Topic will lead to better throughput, so if your use case requires lowest possible latency go with this approach. I'd suggest starting with the multiple topics in 1 DStream first. If that isn't meeting your needs then go for creating multiple DStreams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data in different topics is same and you have same processing logic while consuming data, you can consume from different topics in same stream and do aggregation. If  processing logic is different for different topics, then specify concurrentThreads as 4 and then do aggregation among 4 streams. You can check [spark structured streaming](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html) documentation for consuming from multiple topics.

```
val df = spark
  .readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "host1:port1,host2:port2")
  .option("subscribe", "topic1,topic2")
  .load()
df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")
  .as[(String, String)]

<--- your aggregation logic here --->
```